# My facebook comment plugin is working fine on Local host but not on our company dedicated server . Why?

Tags: php, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have used facebook comment plugin in my website. On localhost I have tested it it works fine. We can comment using our facebook id. But Tommorow i just copied the same code that i have been using on localhost to .aspx page and published it to our company dedicated server. Now the facebook comment box is rendering on required location , people can log into using facebook id but when to click "comment button " nothing happens. Comment is not posting to our .aspx page . In order to confirm that are comments going to facebook i use http://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids="my url". But it is showing empty. So question is why does i am not able to post comments when using Comapany dedicated server? Thanks. regards.

Updated:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="myurl" />
<meta property="og:title" content="mytitle" />
<meta property="og:image" content="imgaddress" />
<meta property="og:description" content="desc about site" />
<script>    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=appid";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="my test server path" data-width="600"></div> 
        </center>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you show your code for facebook comment plugin?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser error console?

Comment: its giving me some error in parsing.

Comment: pasted the comments script right before closing </body> instead of right after openning.

Comment: i don't understand.? please elaborate.

Comment: I have only posted the code that i have used. Not used either body or Head tag.

Comment: but you are putting these script on page some where in body tag. IF yes then put it at the end.

Comment: no i am not using body tag. Working with master page . writing all my code in content place holder. NOT USING BODY AND HEAD TAG.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38147/discussion-between-r-sharma-and-sain-pradeep)